# javascript Spell Checker

Tags: javascript

We have a input field in which the user will type text and there should be mechanism to check the basic spelling mistakes(general English terms) and highlight the same to the user. The following is the simple example to highlight the issue.

**Ex:** apply leavds today

**Spell checker:** Do you mean: leave leaves etc..

Please suggest a feasible solution to achieve the same.

Thanks
vijay

Comment: Java or Javascript or Both or Fortran?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is too vague, I'll try to decipher it logically,
You need to add a spell check to a web page using javascript (I ignored the java tag)

You can use [Typo.js](http://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/) or [JSpell HTML](http://www.jspell.com/html-spell-checker.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can try rapidSpellCheck. Its a simple JS plugin and compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) (not a javascript solution but a **java** one). As you've also tagged the question **java-ee**, the following could be what you're after. If the input field you're using is to search for something in your own database and you use Hibernate JPA provider in a java-ee application, then you should consider looking at Hibernate Search (which uses Lucene). Using a full-text search engine provides you with many features, including: spelling correction, query term highlighting and type-ahead suggestions.

[This](http://thelabdude.blogspot.ie/2010/06/vinwiki-part-2-full-text-search-with.html) brilliantly crafted blog (*thelabdude*) shows and explains how to implement all these features through a demo application which you can download. The “did you mean” feature you mention is explained mid-way down.